# Error: Cannot find module './server/controllers/meetups-controller'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem with my mean app i get Error: Cannot find module './server/controllers/meetups-controller'. The file is in the right directory but i get the error please help

here is my server code :

```
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var hash = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local' ).Strategy;
var meetupsController = require('./server/controllers/meetups-controller.js');
// mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mean-auth');

// user schema/model
var User = require('./models/user.js');

// create instance of express
var app = express();

// require routes
var routes = require('./routes/api.js');

// define middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// configure passport
passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// routes
app.use('/user/', routes);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client', 'index.html'));
});

// error hndlers
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.end(JSON.stringify({
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  }));
});




app.use(bodyParser());
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/client/js'));

//REST API
app.get('/api/meetups', meetupsController.list);
app.post('/api/meetups', meetupsController.create);
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: try to load nearer file from current folder, after success one folder deeper, eg. ./server/test.js

Comment: no luck any other ideas

Comment: is require('./test.js') throwing exception?

Comment: try this one require(__dirname + '/server/....');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but may be you do not need to explicitly mention the file extension.

Not tested but you can try by removing the `js` part

```
var meetupsController = require('./server/controllers/meetups-controller');
```